# Why any created color box is not showing up at simulator?

Tags: react-native

native. My problem, as i said, my boxes created by this code , not showing up at simulator

I did basic coding to create styles and render.

```
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View styles={styles.style1}></View>
        <View styles={styles.style2}></View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container:{
    backgroundColor: '#FFEB3B',
    flex: 1
  },
  style1:{
    backgroundColor: '#FF5722',

  },
  style2:{
    backgroundColor: '#607D8B',
    flex:1
  }
});
```

There is no error messages showing up.

Answer (score 1):

View will render only if it have some content in it, as you have nothing added inside the view.So it will not take any height or width .So in your case you have to provide some height and width to both views.

```
style1:{
backgroundColor: '#FF5722',
height: 200,
width: 200,
},

style2:{
backgroundColor: '#607D8B',
height: 200,
width: 200,
}
```

Comment: Also the OP has a typo `<View styles={styles.style1}></View>` should be `<View style={styles.style1}></View>` and the same goes for the following `<View>`

Comment: Yes,exactly this one is the correct format style={styles.style1}

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I solved the problem with style= instead of using styles=